# Rails credentials not working on travis CI - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci

Im using Rails credentials to store sensitive information on my app. locally it works fine, by calling `Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:key_secret]` for example.

my credentials are stored as:

```
test:
  key_secret: <key>
development:
  key_secret: <key>
```

Travis doesnt pick this information, when tests start running, then it beaks the build.

```
Failure/Error: HMAC_SECRET = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:key_secret]
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

What I did:

- I ran `travis encrypt RAILS_MASTER_KEY='cat config/master.key' --add env`  this added an encryption key to my `.travis.yml` file.
- Commited it to the (private)repo, and then added my `master.key` for decryption, on travis enviroment variables sections as `RAILS_MASTER_KEY`

Nothing changed, I debugged some lines on travis and got:

```
:test # Rails.env.to_sym
#<ActiveSupport::EncryptedConfiguration:0x0000558fe0675870 @key_path=#<Pathname:/home/api/limpar/current/config/master.key>, @content_path=#<Pathname:/home/api/limpar/current/config/credentials.yml.enc>, @env_key="RAILS_MASTER_KEY", @raise_if_missing_key=false> #Rails.application.credentials
```

Anything else I can test to make it work on Travis CI?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
- echo "$RAILS_MASTER_KEY" > config/master.key
```

to my `before_install` segment on `travis.yml` file, solved it for me!